# How to share docker volume between two services with one being the source of truth?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, volume

I have two services in my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - "html:/usr/share/nginx/html/"
  php:
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
      - "html:/usr/share/nginx/html/"

volumes:
  html:
```

and a Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY public_html/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

but when I run `docker-compose up --build` it does no update the files in the volume. I have to delete the volume for the files inside `public_html` to update on both services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `volumes` in your docker-compose has precedence over the files you have added in the Dockerfile.

Those containers don't take the content you are trying to add in your Dockerfile - they are taking the content from the `html` volume which is living in your host machine.

Those are two different techniques - mounting volume vs. adding files to an image in `Dockerfile`.

One solution, without using `volumes` might be to build both images every time:

`PhpDockerfile` content:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
COPY public_html/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

and the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - php
  php:
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: PhpDockerfile
```

**EDIT**:
The second approach, using volumes instead of adding them in `dockerfile` (will be quicker since you don't have to build each time, better for development environment):

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - "./public_html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/"
  php:
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
      - "./public_html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/"
```

and then you can remove the

```
COPY public_html/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

from your `dockerfile`.
Note that you might need to use the full path instead of a relative path in the `docker-compose` file.

Comment: Yes, right. My question is - can I do anything to stop this and get the content from the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, give me a sec and I'll edit the answer

Comment: @maxisme did it answer your question? you didn't accept my answer :)

Comment: Is there no other way? I can't use relative volumes and I also would rather not have 2 dockerfiles!

Comment: well, you can keep your original approach, but then the `COPY public_html/* /usr/share/nginx/html/` is redundant. You'll have to fill the volume with data the first time (assuming you're not going to delete the volume)